# In my MySQL query I'm getting "Cannot add foreign key constraint error", what could be the reason?

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL query I'm getting this error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint error

What could be the reason?

```
CREATE TABLE `social_account` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('facebook','Twitter') DEFAULT NULL,
  `pageid` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accesstoken` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pagename` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProfilePicture` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_url` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accesstokensecreat` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_expire` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_user_social_account` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_social_account` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Did this `CREATE TABLE` statement actually cause this error?

Comment: What is the error message? Can you format your code as well?

Comment: do you have a table called `user`?

Comment: @Ezenhis yup ..i 'm creating the new with " user " name

Comment: @PaulFloyd  Cannot add foreign key constraint error”,

Answer (score 0):

may be Your Foreign key datatype is not matched with the referring table

Comment: i changed it with same data type but still getting same error.